# Update IMemoryCache server-side

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to cache some data in our webshop for 1 hour and I'm using `Asp.Net Core 2.1` `IMemoryCache`. Is it possible to update the cache every hour automatically?

Normally the cache will be refreshed after a webuser asks for cached data that as expired. But the caching process takes some time and I want to be sure that no user get's a 'slow' website because his request is resetting some cached data.

I can't find any `IMemoryCache` method to do this. I think it's possible with a scheduled task that triggers some updating functions every hour (+1 second?), but then with some bad luck the scheduled task is just a little bit later then a user request and the user is updating the cache instead of my scheduled task.

```
return _cache.GetOrCreate("FullNav", entry =>
{
    entry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    //calculate fullnav
    return fullnav;
});
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You might try to use the `RegisterPostEvictionCallback` method to register a callback that will repopulate the cache:  http://vibrantcode.com/AspNetDocsPreview/performance/caching/memory.html

Comment: Did you check the [Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.set?view=aspnetcore-2.1) methods? Or using [AbsoluteExpiration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycacheentryoptions.absoluteexpiration?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Caching_Memory_MemoryCacheEntryOptions_AbsoluteExpiration) instead of `AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow` ?

Comment: You should probably *not* use time-based expiration at all or at least a period longer than the scheduled job's, so entries will only be replaced by the scheduled job. If you warm the cache during startup, you'll only have to worry about entries getting evicted due to memory pressure

Comment: Use a distributed memory cache, such as redis. Just write to it (no expiration) and when our data changes (i.e. user edits product description), generate the new data and update the cache, this way your cache is always up2date and never expires. Alternatively, store the generated data in a database (or file system) when its changed, then retrieve it from there on a cache miss. This way generation happens in the backend where on cache misses the processing time is kept to a minimum buy only reading the data from db or filesystem

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't found the Set functions and expected that AbsoluteExpiration and AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow do almost the same (and because I wanted to cache items for 1 hour from now, I chose the second one. But I think you mean its the best way to set no expiration time and us the Set function in a scheduled task to recalculate the cache values, right?

Comment: @Tseng I like your solution, but it will not fit my current project as the data is generated externally and I don't know when there are changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best answer given in the comments by Panagiotis Kanavos:

1. Use Set() instead of GetOrCreate() to force a reset of the cache, even if it already exists. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.set?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
2. Don't use an expiration time, even AbsoluteExpiration is not necessary.
3. Create a scheduled task that calls this method every x time

In code:

```
fullnav = ''; //calculate fullnav
_cache.Set("FullNav",fullnav);
```

When calling the cached fullnav, it's smart to use `TryGetValue` and call the set method when the cache isn't already available.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `AbsoluteExpiration`

```
DateTime cacheEntry;

// Look for cache key.
if (!_cache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.Entry, out cacheEntry))
{
    // Key not in cache, so get data.
    cacheEntry = DateTime.Now;

    // Set cache options.
    var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
        // Keep in cache for this time, reset time if accessed.
        .SetAbsoluteExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

    // Save data in cache.
    _cache.Set(CacheKeys.Entry, cacheEntry, cacheEntryOptions);
}

return View("Cache", cacheEntry);
```

---

`GetOrCreate` version, which is suggested by @Panagiotis Kavavos

```
var cacheEntry = _cache.GetOrCreate(CacheKeys.Entry, entry =>
{
    entry.AbsoluteExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    return DateTime.Now;
});

return View("Cache", cacheEntry);
```

**Edit**

> **AbsoluteExpiration**
>
> Gets or sets an absolute expiration date for the cache entry.
>
> **AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow**
>
> Gets or sets an absolute expiration time, relative to now.

[Rerefence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycacheentryoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow is time offset specific, whereas AbsoluteExpiration is Date specific.

Comment: `GetOrCreate` with `AbsoluteExpiration` is safer in this case. Using `TryGet` a race condition if two or more requests try to make the same call.

Comment: This code will just do what the code in the original question does. It will do that using more lines of code also being less thread safe.

Comment: OP is using `AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow` where as I am suggesting `AbsoluteExpiration `

Comment: Well, I thought the main problem facing the OP was that he wanted to avoid the "cold cache" delay when a user tries to get an item from the cache after the item has been purged. Does this code solve that issue?

Comment: @mortb not setting an expiration period would solve the issue

Comment: This answer seems to be useless indeed, @mortb you understand my problem en I think PanagiotisKanavos has the solution in the comments on my first post in his thread.

Answer (score 0):

Naive implementation:

```
    // add proper code to populate
    var x = "hello";
    _cache.Set(x, NullChangeToken.Singleton);

    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
        // add proper code to repopulate
        var y = "new value";
        _cache.Set(y, NullChangeToken.Singleton);
    });
```

The `NullChangeToken` will never change and thus the value does not expire automatically. The value will be replaced by subsequent calls to `_cache.Set(...)`

The implementation does not take into account that the item may be purged due to memory pressure. I think it might be better to implement this as a service class that is instantiated as a singleton. The service class would do the same thing, but keep the "expensive" item in an instance variable.